# Publish a spreadsheet as a web app through Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am trying to publish a spreadsheet as a web app through the script code embedded in another spreadsheet.

- I want to copy a spreadsheet
- I want to publish the copied spreadsheet as a web app
- I want to retrieve the public url of the web app interface just created
- **I want to get the result of the doGet() function embedded in the copied spreadsheet**

Thanks to Tanaike's help I wrote this code:

```
 // Copies the spreadsheet
 var repliesFile = responseTemplate.makeCopy('risposte', newFolder);

 // Publish the spreadsheet (Drive Api is enabled)
 Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, repliesFile.getId(), 1);
 var webAppUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=" + repliesFile.getId();
```

**Problem:** using webAppUrl I can see the published spreadsheet but what I want is the html returned by the doGet() function in the copied spreadsheet. In a few words, the same interface I get if I publish the web app via 'Publish -> Deploy as Web App'. Is there a way to get it? A few images are attached (don't mind the template variables in the html template).

Thanks for all the help you can give me!

[image: doGet() funtion in the copied spreadsheet embedded code]
[image: the web app interface I get via 'Publish -> Deploy as Web App']
[image: what I get with my code]

Comment: Hello, to understand you question better, can you please provide the content of `webApp.html` and the link to your previous post where you were helped by Tanaike? And maybe your spreadsheet after removing private information.

Answer (score 0):

### To obtain the URL of a WebApp you can use the method [`ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#geturl)

Note that this method will only work once you deployed the script as a Web App. And the WebApp will only work as intended if it contains a `doGet()` function.

Comment: Thanks for answering and sorry for the late reply. I think what I want here is something different: I would like to deploy a spreadsheet 1 web app using code in a spreadsheet 2. Then, I am looking for a way to obtain in the spreadsheet 2 the public url of the published web app (spreadsheet 1). Maybe it is something impossible to do, need to find a different way to obtain what I want..

Comment: Obtaining in one Web App the URL of another Web App is unfortunately not directly possible. A workaround I can think of is calling `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` from the spreadsheet1 script, store it somewhere (e.g. in a spreadsheet cell) and retrieve it form there with your spreadsheet2 script.